# Linux outputs variable with single quotes around special characters

Tags: linux, variables, logging, special-characters, single-quotes

Korn shell 93u+

```
2>&1 | tee -a ${LOGFILE}
```

puts the output to a file.  I want to add that command to each function I run.  For example:

```
_cleanup_test  2>&1 | tee -a ${LOGFILE}
```

That works fine.

But I want to replace 2>&1 | tee -a ${LOGFILE} with a variable, so I made

```
logit='2>&1 | tee -a ${LOGFILE}'
```

That way I can have

```
_cleanup_test  $logit
```

But when I run the .ksh it reads it as

```
+ _cleanup_test '2>&1' '|' tee -a '${LOGFILE}'
```

I even tried to escape characters and a bunch of other things.  How do I have it read that variable without the single quotes?

Comment: You can't generally store code (especially redirections, etc.) in a variable and expect it to work without considerable extra effort. Consider the alternate `( cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; ...) 2>&1 | tee -a "${LOGFILE}"`.

Comment: @twalberg You mean do it at the command level say inside the function rather than trying to do it at the function level?  That might be best.